# Group sum of n consecutive numbers of array

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

So I have an array like `{1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7}` and I have to make a new array containing the sums of each 3 consecutive elements like `{7, 9, 10, 11, 15}`.
So far I got here and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int a[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7};
int lung = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int *l = new int[10];

int calc(int *a, int m)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int stmax = (lung - m) - 1; 
    for(int st=0;st <= stmax; st++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[st+i];
        }
        l[st] = sum;
    }
    return 0;   
}

void main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7};
    cout << calc(a, 3)<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < lung; i++)
    {
        cout << l[i] << " | ";
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set `sum=0;` after each iteration

```
for(int st=0;st <= stmax; st++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[st+i];
        }

        l[st] = sum;


    }
```

and also you have to declare `int stmax = (lung - m); //ommit -1`

and in the `main` function print the array till `stmax`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= stmax; i++)
    {
        cout << l[i] << " | ";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out later that day that i had to update the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int a[] = { 1,4,2,3,5,3,7};
int lung = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

int *l = new int[10];

void calc(int* a, int m){
    a += 1;  // Increment pointer
    for (int st = 0; st <m; st++){
        l[st] = a[st-1]+a[st]+a[st+1];
    }
}

int main(){
    calc(a, lung-2);
    for (auto i = 0; i < lung-2; i++){
        std::cout << l[i] << " ";
    }
}
```